# Why is the total differential of a function just the sum of the components?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

In a multivariable calculus class, I was taught if $f$ is a function of $x, y, z$, the total differential of the function is:
$$df = f_xdx + f_ydy + f_zdz$$
Intuitively, it seems that there are missing terms to me. For example, shouldn't there be some sort of interactive term to account for how $x$ and $y$ change together? Or do these terms just "go away" under a technical derivation? Or maybe these terms or never there to begin with? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As the answers below explain, those higher-order terms “go away” because the differential is a *linear* approximation to the function’s change near a point.

Answer (score 2):

The total differential of $f$ at a point $p$, denoted by $df_p$, is the linear map best approximating $f$ around $p$, meaning that
$$f(p+h) = f(p) + df_p(h) + o(\|h\|).$$
This implies that $df_p(h)$ must be the directional derivative of $f$ in direction $h$, and you get your definition (remembering that for example $dx$ is the linear map giving $1$ when eating the unit vector in direction $x$, and $x$ on the unit vectors in direction $y$ and $z$). The mixed terms you mention indeed appear in the higher derivatives.

Comment: The error term is nor always quadratic, that requires more regularity.

Comment: In the definitions I’ve seen, the error term is usually given as $o(h)$ instead, which is somewhat different from being quadratic, as @Ian writes. I don’t think this affects the point you’re trying to make, though.

Comment: @amd Well $O(x^2)$ means that the error is at most quadratic, so it should be the same, no? I've never been so good with all this little/big-O notation actually.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Proving the $O(\| h \|^2)$ error bound requires another derivative to exist. In general you only get $o(\| h \|)$.

Comment: @Ian Ah, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

The "interaction" terms are higher order in $\Delta x $ and $\Delta y $. For example $(x+h)(y+k)-xy=xk+yh+hk $; for small k,h and nonzero x,y the last term is much smaller than the first two, enough to vanish to first order (i.e in any directional derivative).